# Inequality about Euclid norm. $|y_1-x_1|+ \cdots +|y_n-x_n| \leqq \sqrt{n} ||y-x||.$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Does this inequality about Euclid norm hold?

\begin{align}
&|y_1-x_1|+ \cdots +|y_n-x_n|
\leqq \sqrt{n} ||y-x||. \\
&\text{ where }
||y-x||:=
\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+ \cdots +(y_n-x_n)^2}
\end{align}

I substituted some concrete examples (when $n=3$),

$x=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix},
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
3\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
or
$x=
\begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix},
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
12 \\
4\\
6\\
\end{pmatrix}$
and so on, and the inequality above held.

But I couldn't prove $|y_1-x_1|+ \cdots +|y_n-x_n|
\leqq \sqrt{n} ||y-x||.$

How can I prove this inequality?

Comment: Take a look at [am-qm inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities). There should be plenty of proofs available in lots of places.

Comment: Or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $(|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|,\dots,|x_n-y_n|)$ and $(1,1,\dots,1)$.